# MongoDB query return n documents per match

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a resources collection which contains a non-unique cluster field (Number). The data looks something like:

```
{
  { 
    _id: "0"
    cluster: 15
  },
  { 
    _id: "1"
    cluster: 4
  },
  { 
    _id: "2"
    cluster: 15
  },      
  { 
    _id: "3"
    cluster: 8
  },
  ...
}
```

My goal is to find n number of resources per cluster match. For instance, lets suppose I want to get five resources matching cluster 1, eight resources matching cluster 2 and seven resources matching cluster 3.

Currently I can solve the problem by sending 3 separate requests such as:

```
db.resources.find({cluster: 1}).limit(5)
```

Unfortunately, this becomes very inefficient as the number of clusters I am searching for grows. Furthermore, I am aware that I can do an aggregation and group by cluster but as far as I understand it that will only give me access to the first (not the n'th) number of resources per cluster. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation pipeline with $facet, and run parallel `$match` and `$limit` stage for each cluster inside the `$facet` operation. And finally combine all the arrays from $facet stage.

Try this:

For cluster : 1,3 with limit of 2,3 respectively, you can use the below query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      "cluster1": [
        {
          $match: {
            "cluster": 1
          }
        },
        {
          $limit: 2
        }
      ],
      "cluster2": [
        {
          $match: {
            "cluster": 3
          }
        },
        {
          $limit: 3
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      items: {
        $concatArrays: [
          "$cluster1",
          "$cluster2"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$items"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$items"
    }
  }
])
```

check the result on [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KW9RAH66Nu9)

To generalize the above aggregation query, you can construct the `facetQuery` and `concatArrays` depending on your incoming object(`obj`) containing different `cluster` and their respective `limits`.

```
// Lets say obj contains cluster and respective limit in an array
var obj = [{
    cluster:1,
    limit:2
},{
    cluster:2,
    limit:3
},{
    cluster:3,
    limit:1
}]

var facetQuery = {};
var concatArrays = [];

obj.forEach((key,index) => {
    facetQuery["cluster"+key.cluster] = [{
        $match : {
            cluster : key.cluster
        }
    },{
        $limit: key.limit
    }]
    concatArrays.push("cluster"+key.cluster)
})

db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: facetQuery
  },
  {
    $project: {
      items: {
        $concatArrays: concatArrays
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$items"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$items"
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the shortest dynamic possible answer , as i know
https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ni-irGhtp85

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{ $group: {
   _id: "$cluster",
   count: { $sum: 1 }
  }
},
{ $project: {
    "_id": 0,
    "cluster": "$_id",
    "count": "$count"
  }
}
 ])
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but this query only returns the number of documents per cluster. If that is the case, this answer doesn't answer my question.

Comment: yes, it would return the number of documents per cluster, i checked that i forgot the limit option , please can you further explain what type of result you require.

Comment: This answer is not what OP asked. He wants certain count of each cluster, not just one cluster

Comment: Ravi shankar Bharti it would return certain count of each cluster, not just one cluster, have you checked it on given url of mongoplayground, this is clear answer

Comment: I am not interested in the count. I need to retrieve some specified number of documents per each cluster as @RaviShankarBharti has shown with his query.